# Problem on printing "Ethernet.localIP()" to Serial Monitor

Tags: arduino, serial, programming, c++

I am using Arduino Uno and the Ethernet Shield. I have the following code:

```
// My custom class.
class Logger {
  public:
    // Note: The 'message' is an Arduino's String object.
    void serial(String message) {
      Serial.print(message);
    }
};

void setup() {
  Logger logger;
  EthernetClient client;

  ...

  logger.serial("Some text: " + Ethernet.localIP()); // Here I have problems (keep reading for more information)
}
```

When I start Arduino then the Serial Monitor displays `G+dsé&¿` instead of `Some text: 192.123.0.4` (note: `192.123.0.4` is the Internet IP assigned to Arduino). However, if I run `Serial.print(Ethernet.localIP());` it works as expected and prints `Some text: 192.123.0.4`.

Why does it happen? How can I solve the problem?

---

Furthermore (see comments):

```
logger.serial("Some text: " + 'other text'); // works
logger.serial("Some text: " + "other text"); // doesn't work (error is: "invalid operands of types 'const char [11]' and const char [10] to binary 'operator+'")
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on your error messages, especially this one:

```
error is: "invalid operands of types 'const char [11]' and const char [10] to binary 'operator+'"
```

it looks like the "+" operator isn't taking advantage of a default constructor that would convert a primitive "const char[]" data type into a String. Just on a hunch, see if this works:

```
logger.serial (String ("Some text") + Ethernet.localIP);
```

It basically forces the compiler to turn "Some text" into a String object so that the "+" operator can deal with it.

Specifically, C++ treats the string constants you passed as type const char[], a constant array of characters. The "+" operator you're trying to use is actually a method of object String; the "+" operator built into C++ doesn't know how to concatenate strings on its own, so the authors of String added their own spin on "+" that knows how to put to String objects together. Class String has a constructor that can turn a const char[] into a String object, but due to the way C++'s implicit type conversion rules work, C++ isn't willing to implicitly run the constructor if you just add two arrays of characters. However, if you explicitly convert the first array of characters into a String object, the String object's "+" operator can run, concatenating the second string onto the first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasonably certain you are running out of memory or stack space.

[Arduino Serial print changes behavior of program undesireably](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42049/arduino-serial-print-changes-behavior-of-program-undesireably/42069#42069)

The + gives rise to a new string, and they are very memory hungry.